# Are there any methods in Spotify API that can auto-correct search keywords?

Tags: api, spotify, autocorrect

I am planning to use the Spotify API to fetch some data, feeding track name and artist as search keywords. However, the track name and artist data I have some parsing errors, and I was wondering if there are any methods in Spotify API that auto-corrects the keywords.

For example, Google will fetch me documents about Radiohead even if I search for 'Radiohea','Radihead', and so. Also, the Last.fm API provides a method named 'track.getCorrection', which does jobs similar to those I explained above.

Here is the explanation of the method from the official Last.fm API website:
'Use the last.fm corrections data to check whether the supplied track has a correction to a canonical track.'

Does anyone know if such method exists in Spotify API?

Comment: You should ask in spotify forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no auto-correction engine. The closest Spotify gets to having a search engine is the [search endpoint](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/):

You can search, for instance, like this:

```
query = 'radio head'
```

and then

```
query_results = sp.search(q=query, type='playlist')
```

would return

```
...u'playlist'...{u'name': u'Air/Zero 7/Thievery Corp/Radio Head/Massive Attack/Morcheeba',...
```

but that requires that the playlist user spelled it wrong too. That is as far as a typo can get you, I'm afraid.

A workaround is fetching the artist using the last.fm API, use its auto-correction tool and then feed this result into Spotify API, either using `artist`, `track` or `search` endpoints.

I highly recommend you using more than one API for your app, as each one has its own limitations.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I totally missed out that solution.. I should do as you explained. Just one more question..  When I run the search method, it fetches multiple matches(the json result is too complicated to index and use) but I only want to get the first match. Do you know how to give result limits to the search method? Either by the search method implemented in the spotipy library or by executing a url.

Comment: @user3052069 you'll have to get used to `json`. it takes a while but you'll get there. do `query_results['playlists']['items'][0]['external_urls']`and you'll reach the `url`. hope this helps.

Comment: @user3052069 you can always print the whole result and try to understand the data structure better, and how to dig into the nested dictionaries. like this: `json.dumps(query_results, sort_keys=True, indent=4)`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. As you explained, I got the first element of the result by indexing similar to what you used as an example, but I was wondering if it is possible to get just 1 result in the first place. Wouldn't that help reduce some (a tiny bit of?) computation time? Or would that be too tiny to effect the computation load? I am sending url requests for huge amount of data, which takes lots and lots of time... although it seems url requests, and not the local computation,  are taking up all the time.

Comment: requests are made for the whole data. you have to index it in order to fetch specific items, like explained above. in your machine, complexity arises from looping through query results, and not by indexing results in the first place. but if you request a huge amount of data, it takes time. hope this helps

Comment: oh, I may have used the wrong word.. I meant I successed in looping. Sorry for my unclear description. Aside from that, do you mean there are no means in Spotipy to give limits to the number of matches that the search method retrieves? Because the Last.fm API allows you to give limits to the number of both the results and the pages, as described [here](http://www.last.fm/api/show/track.search).

Comment: Spotify also allows `limit` for `search`, so you can set the maximum number of items in the response (as set in the query or by default). that can help you. Just add a parameter `limit=n` and pass it. please consider accepting my answer for all the help. cheers.